# How to set aria attributes to highcharts tooltips

Tags: javascript, highcharts, wai-aria

I have a chart (Highcharts) written in a React application with custom formatted tooltips; however, screen readers will not announce the tooltip content when 'tabbed' through the points.

I wrote some JavaScript that solves my problem and announces the tooltips on mouseOut as they should be announced without creating unnecessary elements in the DOM.

```
point: {
    events: {
        mouseOut: function () {
            let ariaText = this.category + ', Projected Savings: $ ' + this.projectedSavingsFormatted + ', Target Savings: ' + targetSavingsFormatted + ', Time to Achieve: ' + this.timeToAcheive + ' months';
            let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('div.highcharts-tooltip')[0];
            tooltips.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].setAttribute('role', 'tooltip');
            tooltips.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].setAttribute('aria-live', 'assertive');
            tooltips.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].setAttribute('aria-label', ariaText);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is this:  How do I clean this up?  There has to be a more efficient way to write this function.

Comment: The irony is that a blind person is unlikely to be interacting with your site using a mouse. Off topic but you can use `querySelector` to get the first element.

Comment: Highcharts accessibility API is limited as I understand it.  mouseOut seemed to be the best way to bring the tooltips 'live', as I do not want them to be prematurely announced.

Comment: I am trying to combine the multiple 'tooltips.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].setAttribute('', '')' lines..

Comment: A screen reader user will only use the keyboard, not a mouse.  Adding `aria-live` will only be effective if you are changing the text within the tooltip.  Any time the text in the tooltip changes, it'll be read by a screen reader.  Adding `aria-live` in and of itself won't cause anything to be read.  Changing the `aria-label` of an element will not be read by a screen reader.  When focus moves to the element with the new `aria-label`, the new label will be read, but the changing of the label itself will not be read.  That is, `aria-live` does not read `aria-label` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get just a single element, use [`querySelector(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `querySelectorAll(…)[0]`:

```
let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('div.highcharts-tooltip')[0];
// becomes:
let tooltips = document.querySelector('div.highcharts-tooltip');
```

But, based on your code, it seems there is no need to select the `div` – if you just want the first `span`, select it right away, without storing the parent node:

```
let tooltip = document.querySelector('div.highcharts-tooltip span');
tooltip.setAttribute('role', 'tooltip');
tooltip.setAttribute('aria-live', 'assertive');
tooltip.setAttribute('aria-label', ariaText);
```

To save few characters and hopefully make the long string clearer, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of chaining `'…' + … + '…'`:

```
let ariaText = this.category + ', Projected Savings: $ ' + this.projectedSavingsFormatted + ', Target Savings: ' + targetSavingsFormatted + ', Time to Achieve: ' + this.timeToAcheive + ' months';
// becomes:
let ariaText = `${this.category}, Projected Savings: $ ${this.projectedSavingsFormatted}, Target Savings: ${targetSavingsFormatted}, Time to Achieve: ${this.timeToAcheive} months`;
// notice the backticks (``) instead of quotes ('')
```

So, your function could become:

```
point: {
    events: {
        mouseOut: function () {
            let ariaText = `${this.category}, Projected Savings: $ ${this.projectedSavingsFormatted}, Target Savings: ${targetSavingsFormatted}, Time to Achieve: ${this.timeToAcheive} months`;
            let tooltip = document.querySelector('div.highcharts-tooltip span');
            tooltip.setAttribute('role', 'tooltip');
            tooltip.setAttribute('aria-live', 'assertive');
            tooltip.setAttribute('aria-label', ariaText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner!  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. However, as @DominicTobias noted, i'm not sure if using `mouseOut` makes any sense with screenreaders… I don't know much about HighCharts though.